# php5 and phpmyadmin not installing

Tags: package-management, software-installation, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I have installed mysql, mysql-server, apache2 and many more. May be I have installed some wrong PPA or programs which cause this problem. Basically, I need to run local server (eg. for wordpress). So I need to localhost/phpmyadmin. Somehow localhost is working (it shows it's default page) but localhost/phpmyadmin not working.

When I tried to `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, It gives following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

phpmyadmin : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libapache2-mod-php5filter but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-cgi but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-mysql but it is not going to be installed or
                       php5-mysqli but it is not installable or
                       php5-mysqlnd but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php-gettext but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I tried `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5` , It gives following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14 is to be installed
                       Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Again, I tried to install missing phps-common by `sudo apt-get install php5-commom`, It shows php5-common is already it's newest version. Here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14 is to be installed
                       Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
maddy@maddy-PC:/$ sudo apt-get install php5-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

So, guys I need your help to install phpmyadmin.

**UPDATE**
Here is an output of `grep -R --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Beta amd64 (20150805)]/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/upubuntu-com-office-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cordova-ubuntu-ppa-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cordova-ubuntu/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-tor-browser-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

and output of `apt-cache policy php5-common`

```
php5-common:
  Installed: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5 0
        500 http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

**UPDATE 2** Here is an output of `aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, !?version(CANDIDATE))'`

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to update the package lists to correct these missing files
i   google-chrome-stable            - The web browser from Google               
i   nodejs                          - Node.js event-based server-side javascript
i   oracle-java8-installer          - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8   
i   oracle-java8-set-default        - Set Oracle JDK 8 as default Java          
i   tor-browser                     - Tor Browser Bundle
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? `14.04`/`15.10`?

Comment: @blade19899 14.04 LTS

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get -f install`!

Comment: @blade19899 it gives same problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give me the outputs of `grep -R --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt` and `apt-cache policy php5-common`, then we can solve it.

Comment: @ByteCommander updated

Comment: Thanks. Now I also need the output of `aptitude search '?narrow(?installed, !?version(CANDIDATE))'`. Could you please add that to your question as well?

Comment: @ByteCommander output updated

Comment: Check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` - I think they are basically the same. Compare only lines that do *not* start with a `#` symbol. If all those lines are identical in both files, delete one of them. Otherwise you will get warnings about duplicate source.list entries.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get clean ; sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists ; sudo apt-get update` to clean the package cache and reload all package lists. Then run `sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5`. Does that cause error messages?

Comment: @ByteCommander there is no google.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: There *must* be one or you gave me wrong or outdated outputs. Update this one: `grep -R --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36789/discussion-between-madan-bhandari-and-byte-commander).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installed version of `php5-common` is incompatible with the packages you want to install.

The reason is very likely a PPA you have added, then installed a newer version of `php5-common` (and maybe other packages) from it and removed or disabled the PPA again.

What we must do now is to remove those "too new" versions from your package cache to prevent another accidental reinstallation of them, and then downgrade the `php5-common` package to the version available from the official repository:

```
sudo apt-get clean    
sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5
```

Only if that did not work yet, run the commands below afterwards. The last one is the same as above.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5
```